# Python subprocess and Flask interaction with mount

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, subprocess

I'm writing a helper app in Flask to automate operations on a server.

I've come up against a very confusing issue and I wanted to ask advice on whether this is an artefact of how I'm using Python's subprocess or if Flask is causing this.

When I run a subprocess call to mount a remote cifs share on the machine running the flask app I'm seeing something rather odd. From the perspective of the Flask app the share is mounted, the files are visible and the app can interact (up load) files to the remote server.

What I can't explain is that this mount is apparently only visible to the thread running Flask. If I SSH in to the machine running Flask and ask for the mounts with 'mount -t cifs' of list the directory at the command line (or from my PC file manager using an SFTP connection) the mount directory is empty and the share isn't reported as mounted.

Running the same command as Flask issues manually at the prompt mounts the share as expected.

I've tried using the Popen and run methods from the subprocess library but the result is the same, it's as if the Flask app has a virtual file system independent of the OS except for the fact that the command issued before the mount is an mkdir to create the a mount point directory below /mnt/remote. That command does propagate too the OS and the new directory is listed when I ls the /mnt/remote directory.

I've also tried running the Popen call with and without shell=True, again both methods worked from within the Flash thread, neither made the mount visible otherwise.

The code snippets are as follows:

`

```
def run_system_command_shell( cmd ):
    result = subprocess.Popen( cmd, shell=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    std_out, std_err = result.communicate()
    rtn_code = result.returncode
    return std_out, std_err, rtn_code

def mount_remote( share_data ):
    cred_file = share_data['cred_file']
    cmd = 'sudo mount '
    cmd = cmd + '-t ' + share_data['share_type'] + ' '
    cmd = cmd + '-o credentials=' + cred_file
    cmd = cmd + ' ' + share_data['share'] + ' ' + share_data['mnt_point']

    std_out, std_err, rtn_code = run_system_command_shell( [cmd] )

    if rtn_code != 0:
        current_app.logger.warning("Could not mount {}. Error: {}".format( share_data['share'], std_out ))
        return False, std_out
    else:
        current_app.logger.info("Mounted {}.".format( share_data['share'] ))

    return True, std_out
```

`

Resulting cmd: 'sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/var/www/ui/config/credentials/10.0.10.10 //10.0.10.10/Install /mnt/remote/10.0.10.10_Install'
`

If this app is to work it needs to mount the remote share across the whole system. Has anybody else run up against this and is there a way to resolve it please?
Thanks, A

Answer (score 0):

How are you running flask? From what you describe, I'd bet you are running it in a container, using Docker.

And then, what you describe is to be actually expected - even if the container is pointing to a mountpoint in the "real" filesystem, the mount exists only inside the container.

Just reconfigure your app to run outside a container.

Comment: No, it's not running is a container or any kind of virtual system. I have Ubuntu server installed "bare" on a Raspberry PI on to which I've installed Apache2 and I'm running Flask using the wsgi daemon. The expected action is that when the thread that's running the Flask app executes the mount command via the Python subprocess method the mounted directory should be visible to the whole OS, not just the thread of the Flask app.